# Replicate Reanimated V1 animation in Reanimated V2/V3

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm working on transitioning (pun intended) my app from React Native Reanimated V1 to V3. I have a transition that I want to stay exactly the same, but I'm not sure how to write it in Reanimated 3. Here is the code for the old transition, which looks like this (ignore the slight up and down motion, the transition is triggered on page scroll).

[image].

```
import {
  Transitioning,
  Transition,
  TransitioningView
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const transition = (
  <Transition.Together>
    <Transition.Out type="scale" durationMs={100} />
    <Transition.Change interpolation="easeInOut" />
    <Transition.In type="scale" durationMs={100} delayMs={50} />
  </Transition.Together>
);

const Component = () => {
  const transitioningRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Transitioning.View ref={transitioningRef} transition={transition}>
      {endThresholdTriggered ? (
        <ChevronDown marginBottom={15} size={25} opacity={1} />
      ) : (
        <Minus marginBottom={15} size={25} opacity={0.45} />
      )}
    </Transitioning.View>
  );
};
```

This is what I have so far with Reanimated 3. It's fading in and out just fine, but doesn't have the "pop" that the old one does. Code for this is below

[image]

```
{startThresholdTriggered ? (
  <Animated.View
    key="startThresholdTriggeredIcon"
    entering={FadeIn}
    exiting={FadeOut}
  >
    <ChevronUp marginTop={15} size={25} opacity={1} />
  </Animated.View>
) : (
  <Animated.View
    key="startThresholdNotTriggeredIcon"
    entering={FadeIn}
    exiting={FadeOut}
  >
    <Minus marginTop={15} size={25} opacity={.45} />
  </Animated.View>
)}
```